# How to create a animated custom pop-up in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I want to display a custom pop-up in my application and I want them to come up with a custom message from the bottom of the page and the back page to be a little darker to draw attention to the pop-up. When the user clicks OK, the opposite happens and the message goes down and the back screen returns to normal. Just like the video!
I have no problem designing posts, buttons and frames on the home screen, and I only have trouble opening pop-ups and animating it.
I used the following code, but despite the fact that Stacklayout was hidden, the whole screen was black and nothing was shown !!! Also, this pop-up was not animated.

User interface:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Azure" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">  
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >  
        <Label Text="Xamarin Monkeys" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium"/> 
        <Image x:Name="imgMonkey" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200"/>  
        <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="btnPopupButton_Clicked" Text="Show Popup"/> 
    </StackLayout>  
</StackLayout>
<ContentView x:Name="popupLoadingView" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">  
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">  
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="White">  
  
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="Black" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>  
            <Label x:Name="lblLoadingText" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Loading..."/> 
        </StackLayout>  
    </StackLayout>  
</ContentView>
```

Programming Codes:

```
private void btnPopupButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    popupImageView.IsVisible = true;  
    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
}
```

This is a preview video link of what I'm trying to create: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YaBAw7rJN8elloBLZojgJzjynDw42dgW/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you can try to use **Rg.Plugins.Popup** to display popup.

Firstly, install Rg.Plugins.Popup plugin by Nuget packages.

[image]

then creating Popup page.

```
<pages:PopupPage
x:Class="FormsSample.popup.popup1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation
        DurationIn="400"
        DurationOut="300"
        EasingIn="SinOut"
        EasingOut="SinIn"
        HasBackgroundAnimation="False"
        PositionIn="Bottom"
        PositionOut="Bottom"
        ScaleIn="1.2"
        ScaleOut="0.8" />
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        Padding="20,0"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Frame
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"
            CornerRadius="10">
            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <Label
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="First Popup Page"
                    TextColor="Black" />
                <ScrollView>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Hello Xamarin Guys" TextColor="Red" />
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="This is Very Awesome Popup Plugins For Xamarin forms" TextColor="LightBlue" />
                            <Button
                                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                                Text="Close"
                                TextColor="Black" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Code behind.

```
public partial class popup1 : PopupPage
{
    public popup1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.PopAsync(true);
    }
}
```

Finally, call this Popup in Another page.

```
  private async void btnPopupButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new popup1());
    }
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is what I use. I've found it to be endlessly useful.

Comment: It was great but it's just a popup! Cannot use a C# code in Popup pages, it is impossible to work with variables (can't set value to variables and can't get ...) I know it's very illogical, but it really does happen